# Lie algebra of projective linear group and one-parameter transformations

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

The vector fields $\partial_x$, $x\partial_x$ and $x^2\partial_x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ have correspondant flows $x\mapsto x+t$, $x\mapsto e^t x$ and $x\mapsto (1-tx)^{-1}$ which are translation, dilations and inversions. By composing them, one easily checks that they generate the group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of transformation of the form
$$
x\mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \quad\quad ad-bc\neq 0.
$$

> Can I compute a basis of the lie algebra of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$  using these transformations?

I have been trying to define paths of transformations through the identity associated to these flows with the purpose to differentiate and see what happens when $t$ small, but I doing something wrong cause I do not obtain something with commutators similar to those of $\partial_x, x\partial_x$ and $x^2\partial_x$. In fact, I don't have it clear how to associate a path in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ to these transformations.

Comment: Do you mean for the flow associated to $x^2 \partial_x$ to be given by 
$x \mapsto \tfrac{x}{1-tx}$ ?

Comment: I am not quite sure how your question is meant. The three vector fields themselves span a Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra of vector fields on $\mathbb R$ and this subalgebra is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of $PGL(2,\mathbb R)$. Are you thinking about some concrete realization of the Lie algebra of $PGL(2,\mathbb R)$ in your question?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, thanks for the clarification. What is the concrete realization obtained from this isomorphism for example (Does that make sense?).